# Is my understanding on Kant's section contained in the critique of pure reason "The transcendental Aesthetic" correct?

Tags: kant, critique-of-pure-reason

I'm attempting to 'self-study' Kant's "critique of pure reason". I've just finished the section "The transcendental Aesthetic"" from both versions of the book and I'm looking for feedback on what I understand.
I made a flowchart on the basic definitions given to me in this section and I want to know what I horribly got wrong. Any help appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good chart. Essentially correct but there are a few small things that are not quite on the mark (a lot of confusion often comes from Kant's spread-out presentation of his theory of experience; later on in the Critique, the full theory of experience is better presented and clarified). 
Empirical knowledge for Kant is conceptualized experience. So it doesn't strictly come from intuitions/immediate experience alone, but intuitions combined with concepts. The perception of an object does not only depend on sensation but on intuitions and concepts. 
The idea of "sensation," as the matter of perception (and the appearance) is very technical in Kant. It doesn't mean what we typically mean (so, Kant, for example, wouldn't say that we can really isolate the sensation component of the perception of any object; sensation is already structured within the pure forms of intuition, structured spatially and temporally, and subsumed under concepts). Kant also talks about the "matter" (as opposed to the "form") component of *perception* and the matter (as opposed to the "form") component of the *object of perception*